# Eliminar datos duplicados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código creado en javascript, el cual me genera una url en el navegador, pero el problema es que cada que filtro me duplica los datos, es decir me vuelve a cargar los filtros seleccionados anteriormente, ocasionando que la url se llene de basura, alguien que me pueda colaborar, le agradezco mucho.

```
function GetFiltersForProducts()
{
    var filters = [];

    $("#estuyo-facets .facet_container").each(function(i, e){         

        var filter = $(e).find(".facet_title");

        var filter_field = filter.attr("id");
        var filter_values = [];

        filter.parent().find(".element_container input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(i, e){

            if($(e).attr('name') != 'Zapatos')
            {
                    var filter_unRepeat = filter_values.push({'values' : $(e).val(), 'name': $(e).attr('name')});

            }

        });

        var filter_shoes = filters.push({ 'filter_field': filter_field, 'filter_values': filter_values });
    });

    return filters;
};
```

Comment: Hey en serio nadie sabe como ayudarme a organizar esta función...

Comment: Hola Juan, no es que nadie sepa pero a veces llegan muchas preguntas de golpe y se puede "perder de vista" Alguien interesado por [tag:javascript] o [tag:jquery] acabará viendola ya que no tiene respuestas. Suerte

Comment: ok muchas gracias, solo espero que alguien me pueda ayudar

Comment: No desesperes. Puedes editar la pregunta para aclarar o poner ejemplos de lo que te genera y lo que deberia generar. Al editar, la pregunta aparece arriba en "activas" y puede que se vea más. Más adelante podrías poner una recompensa para tambien, atraer atención a tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Si tendré en cuenta tu consejo, seré más especifico...

Comment: Ya lo solucione..me llevo varios días pero al fin encontre la solución.:)

Comment: Puedes poner una respuesta y aceptarla tu mismo. Asi otras personas con un fallo similar pueden resolverlo tambien

Comment: si ya habia pensado en eso solo que no he tenido tiempo

Comment: Como ya les habia comentado ya encontre la solución a este problema que tenia, me tocó crear otra funcion que recorriera la cadena, y si encontraba concidencias simplemente no la vovia a mostrar en la url. Acá les dejo el código por si de pronto alguíen lo necesita.

Answer (score 0):

Este fue el código que me toco implementar para solucionar el problema. Esta función simplemente recorre la cadena y me elimina aquellos caracteres o palabras que encuentre repetidas, y luego manda la cadena a la URL.

No la había podido publicar porque no habia tenido el tiempo ni el espacio.

```
function RewriteUrl(url_rewrite) {
    var base_url = '';
    var number_page = parseInt($("#page_current").val()) + parseInt(1);
    var page = '&page=';

    if (url_rewrite != "#?page=1") {
        for (var i = 0; i < window.location.href.length; i++) {
            var l = window.location.href[i];

            if (l == "#") {
                break;
            } else {
                base_url += l;
            }
        }

        var url_array = (base_url + url_rewrite).split("?");
        var url_params = '';
        var arraySinDuplicados = [];

        if (url_array.length > 1) {
            var arrayOriginal = url_array[1].split("&");
            var arraySinDuplicados = arrayOriginal.filter(function(elem, pos) {
                return arrayOriginal.indexOf(elem) == pos;
            });

            url_params = '?' + arraySinDuplicados;

            if (number_page != 1) {

                var url_page = '';
                var url_page_sin_duplicados = [];
                var url_params = '?' + arraySinDuplicados;

                if (url_array.length > 1) {
                    var arrayOriginal = url_array[1].split("&");
                    var url_page_sin_duplicados = arrayOriginal.filter(function(elem, pos) {
                        return arrayOriginal.indexOf(elem) == pos;
                    });

                    url_params = '?' + url_page_sin_duplicados.join('&').replace(/[\d]/, number_page);
                    window.history.pushState({}, document.title, url_array[0] + url_params);
                }

            }

            if (number_page == 1) {
                url_params = '?' + arraySinDuplicados.join('&').replace(/[\d]/, number_page);
                window.history.pushState({}, document.title, url_array[0] + url_params);
            }
        }
    }
};
```